# How to display popup window on the left or right side

Tags: popup-menu

I looked into the `:h popup.txt` and unless i missed something, did not see any mention for setting a popup window on the left or right side.

PS: I'm on Vim 8.2 (latest compiled as of now)

Any example on how to do this?

Comment: Are you sure you mean to use a pop-up window? Perhaps you just want a regular split with a scratch buffer in it? That would make more sense in the context of "left side" or "right side"... A pop-up is primarily floating, so it's really mainly useful to temporarily display some information, but as a permanent window it would quickly become quite bothersome.

Comment: Had half of it nearly figured out, but was kinda stuck on the positioning, since i only saw mention of `center` and such on the `popup.txt`, which didn't really do the trick (not like the way your answer did!) that basically explain this i think.

Comment: Ah! Now I see what you're after... You'll want to look into `win_screenpos('.')`, `winheight('.')`, etc. Keeping it in sync with the current window as it scrolls might be tricky too... And if the current window gets resized. Looks like a lot of work and many details to consider. I wish you luck in implementing your feature!

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I didn't think much about resizing or how to make it scroll at the same time as the cursor/buffer, but the rest is nearly done. Will probably publish it if it look decent enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A popup window in Vim is a "floating" window, so it actually covers the current windows and the text in them.

You can set the line, column and adjust min/max width and height to have a popup cover the left or the right half of the screen.

For example, for a popup covering the left half of the screen:

```
let winid = popup_create('popup', {
    \ 'line': 1,
    \ 'col': 1,
    \ 'minwidth': &columns / 2,
    \ 'minheight': &lines - 1})
```

And one covering the right half:

```
let winid = popup_create('popup', {
    \ 'line': 1,
    \ 'col': &columns,
    \ 'minwidth': &columns / 2,
    \ 'minheight': &lines - 1,
    \ 'pos': 'topright'})
```

See [`:help popup_create-arguments`](https://vimhelp.org/popup.txt.html#popup_create-arguments) for details on the arguments you can pass when creating a popup window.